# What is the best practice for putting classes under package names in Android

Tags: java, android, package

```
Android Studio 0.8.11
```

Hello,

I have just completed a test on Android which was to build an app that takes a live news feed, and display them. However, the instructor was very critical as I put all my classes under one package.

I am just wondering what is the best practice for packaging classes. For my particular test I have the following classes under this package name:

`com.viewsys.ncon`

My classes were these:

```
DBHelper          <-- database creating and ugprading
DetailActivity    <-- activity that add the NconDetailFragment
NconContract      <-- properties of the database schema columns, table name
NconDetailFragment <-- detail fragment
NconListFragment  <-- list fragment
NconViewPager  <-- just the view pager
JsonNewsFeed   <-- class that downloads and parses the json format
MainActivity   <-- Main activity
NewsFeed       <-- class of properties getters/setters for news feed
NewsFeedDB     <-- simple array list to store all the object from the sqlite3 DB
SplashActivity <-- activity that add the splashFragment and the NconListFragment
SplashFragment <-- splash fragment
Utilities <-- just some simple utility functions
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: For me you did fine. You have only thirteen classes. No need to deposit them in different directories.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First you could separate by Model (classes holding your data) and view (everything for the display) and then you could create subpackages for different types of classes.

For Example:

`com.viewsys.ncon`

```
Utilities
```

`com.viewsys.ncon.model`

```
NconContract
JsonNewsFeed
NewsFeed
```

`com.viewsys.ncon.model.db`

```
DBHelper
NewsFeedDB
```

`com.viewsys.ncon.view`

```
NconViewPager
```

`com.viewsys.ncon.view.activities`

```
DetailActivity
MainActivity
SplashActivity
```

`com.viewsys.ncon.view.fragments`

```
NconDetailFragment
NconListFragment
SplashFragment
```

You should try to minimize package dependency cycling. That means one package can depend on an other (or multiple other) package and use their classes but the required package should minimize the dependency to the first package. so the dependeny calls should only go into one direction.

Comment: On my taste keeping "Fragment" or "Activity" suffix in name of class is a little redundant, especially if they are placed into packages which already contains such suffix.

Comment: @AlexK Surely including the suffix' would help code readability outside of the project structure, no?

Comment: In this package architecture, the model class within com.viewsys.ncon.view should have getters and setters of primitive data and object, where in the other hand, com.viewsys.ncon.model.db should only have model that interact with backend and services, is that correct?

Answer (score 9):

Well, I use the following packages-

1. **project.activity** - To put all the activities
2. **project.fragment** - Fragments
3. **project.broadcastReceiver**
4. **project.databaseHelpers** - To put the database helper classes for handling individual tables as well as the main SqliteHelper class which is used to create all the database tables.
5. **project.networkTasks**- all the calls to different APIs of different services go here.
6. **project.services** - This includes the classes which are run as services. Sometimes they overlap with network tasks.
7. **project.general** - This includes general classes. For example, suppose you store student data in a table. Then you can have a Student class. When you create and populate an instance of it, then you can pass the data associated with student with clarity.
8. **project.utils** - This includes utility classes. These classes primarily have static methods. For example, the method to get the HttpResponse as string would be put in one of these classes.

As a general rule, what Steve said is correct, apply the principle of cohesion and coupling.

Answer (score 5):

I structure my packages similarly to Simulant's advice, I've found that to be the best approach to maintaining a well structured project.

However, I also create sub-packages for objects that are extending one of your own objects.
For example:

```
com.viewsys.ncon.view.fragments 
ViewPagerFragment


com.viewsys.ncon.view.fragments.viewpagerfragments
YourViewPagerFragment1 extends ViewPagerFragment
YourViewPagerFragment2 extends ViewPagerFragment
YourViewPagerFragment3 extends ViewPagerFragment
```

This particular approach can be very useful for navigating around your project once it gets a bit bigger, especially if you're extending a lot of previous functionality of custom objects.

Answer (score 4):

Dividing your classes into packages should be done according to the programming principles of Cohesion and Coupling.

Cohesion, simply stated, means that things that are related (or of a type) should go together. For example, your Fragments, and your Activities, as suggested by Simulant.

Coupling is how closely different things depend on one another. Wherever possible, things should be *loosely* coupled - where dependencies only go one way. If two modules depend on one another, we say that they are *tightly* coupled, and they should be part of the same package - though you may want to separate their dependencies by introducing an interface. If the dependencies are only one way (as they should be) then you can have them separated into different packages.

Answer (score 4):

Try always to keep the modules loosely coupled so that it can support scalability in the future. If you put all the classes in the same package it may lead to scalability issues. Keep the fragments, activities, models everything in a different package.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look in this [repository](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices), it presents the best practices for android development, and one of these practices is the java package architecture.

In a nutshell, you can do like this:

```
com.business.project
├─ network
├─ models
├─ managers
├─ utils
├─ fragments
└─ views
   ├─ adapters
   ├─ actionbar
   ├─ widgets
   └─ notifications
```

Activities and fragments are not classified as views, because they are controllers, but they also handles the view, so put in their own packages.